# Ubuntu SDK and QtCreator will not start

Tags: qt-creator, ubuntu-sdk, qt5

I have tried `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-sdk qtcreator qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu qtcreator-plugin-cordovaqt` and then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk` but QtCreator will still not start. It does not show up and after a few tries at starting it the apport gui shows up. I get this error when I run qtcreator in the terminal:

```
Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50001) with this library (version 0x50002)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1178147) and fixed it with a `sudo apt-get upgrade`